# UDP client-server program compiles using gcc but not g++

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, gcc, udp

**Server**:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct sockaddr_in client, server;
    int s, i=0;
    socklen_t n;
    char buf[31];
    s=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server.sin_port=atoi(argv[1]);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "localhost", &(server.sin_addr));
    bind(s,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(server));
    n=sizeof(client);

    while(1) {
        recvfrom(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &n);
        printf("%s", buf);
    }
    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

**Client**:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct sockaddr_in client, server; 
    int s;
    socklen_t n;
    char buf[31];
    char data[23];
    s=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server.sin_port=atoi(argv[2]);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &(server.sin_addr));

    n=sizeof(server);

    while(1) {
        data[0] = 't';
        data[1] = 'e';
        data[2] = 's';
        data[3] = '\0';
        sendto(s, data, strlen(data), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server, n);
    }
    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

This works perfectly fine when compiled using gcc instead of g++. Since I want to use a separate C++ class file, these need to be compiled in g++.

What am I missing?

Comment: You should really include the g++ errors

Comment: If you compile the code as C, then the compiler is more lenient regarding types. C++ is stricter when it comes to types, and you can't use e.g. pointers to one type as a pointer to another type without casting, something which in some cases might not be needed in C.

Comment: +058 094 041 The programs DO compile, but there is no data that is transmitted over the client-server.

Comment: By the way, you don't convert the port number to network byte order. You need to use `htons` to convert the port numbers from host byte order to network byte order.

Comment: You also have *undefined behavior* since you don't send the string terminator to the "server" but it treats the received data as string.

Comment: Lastly, why don't you check for errors? Almost all the function you use will return a value indicating success or failure. If you have a failure then you have no idea about it, and continue blindly.

Comment: So do I use htons(atoi(argv[1]))? And I did try passing a static port, for example, htons(6000).. still does not work.

Comment: I did check for failures, none of the relevant commands output any error(s).

Comment: Just to make sure there are no library issues with g++ while compiling the C code, may be you can try adding an extern "C" {} around the whole code.

Comment: Your *code* must check for errors, after every system call: `socket(), bind(), sendto(), r cvfrom(), ...`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a big problem which could lead to your problems:

```
inet_pton(AF_INET, "localhost", &(server.sin_addr));
```

The `inet_pton` function wants a IP *address* not a hostname. The function does no name lookup. If you checked for errors you would have noticed how it failed.

Comment: Why does it seem to compile on gcc and work fine, though?

Answer (score 0):

The programs as they are showed in the question are neither compilable in gcc nor in g++. Including header files are missing and if you try to compile programs as is vi gcc you got a lot of errors like:

```
error: storage size of ‘client’ isn’t known
struct sockaddr_in client, server;
```

It is sufficient to add following header files to successfully compile in gcc:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
```

But these headers are not sufficient for successful compilation in g++ because there are still unresolved symbols like `close()` and `atoi()`. C compiler allows implicit function declaration so it does not complain about them. But for C++ you have to add another header files that contain declaration of these missing functions:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>      // inet_pton()
#include <unistd.h>         // close()
#include <stdlib.h>         // atoi()
```